# website button onclick offset on the iPad

Tags: jquery, ios, css, ipad

this is a little strange. Just wondering if anyone has experienced this before. I have a website i'm developing and want it to be ipad friendly, everything is working fine except for the input buttons i have on the page are a little off. If i click directly on the input button, it does not do anything. If i click slightly lower than the button, then it registers. Anyone have any ideas on this one? Here's what a button looks like:

```
<input class="productSubmitInput buy" name="AddToCart_Submit" type="submit" value="add to cart" onclick="AddToCart(213585,6732684,'',18,'/Layouts/OnlineShop/featured-product.tpl','xkh0APndsQ8V3J4jtFMwqNwsy74=',true);return false;">
```

Comment: Strange, mind creating a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or linking to a page where this occurs?

Comment: Here you go: http://goo.gl/4w17QV  It's on the add to cart icon in the featured product on that page.

Comment: Sorry for slow reply had to get to my ipad, but I have just tested it on my iPad and it seems to working just fine. Whether you changed something since asking I don't know.

Comment: yea, i changed the way the button was loading up. It's good to go now. Thanks anyway!